How to annotate a variable in Python based on a type that depends on the operating system?
Say one develops an application that should run on Windows and on Linux and the application uses the pyserial package which provides the type serial.serialposix.Serial when installed in Linux and the type serial.serialwin32.Serial when installed in Windows. Is it possible to annotate the variable type, so that the linter knows which type to use based on the OS?
import serial
from serial.serialposix import Serial as PosixSerial
from serial.serialwin32 import Serial as Win32Serial

# linter complains on Windows
serial_port: PosixSerial = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')

# linter complains on Linux
serial_port: Win32Serial = serial.Serial('COM1')

# linter complains on both Windows and Linux
serial_port: PosixSerial | Win32Serial = serial.Serial(f"{name}") 


See https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec/directives.html#version-and-platform-checking. But you shouldn't need to do this - the typeshed stubs package https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stubs/pyserial/serial/init.pyi already handles it for you.

That is an interesting alternative. Thanks for the suggestion.

There are some constant literals for python installations, two of them are sys.platform and os.name.
os.name is more general and will be nt (Windows), posix (linux) or java. (Check out sys.platform if you need fine grained options).
The following code creates a platform-aware variable Serial, Win32Serial and PosixSerial are TypeAlias that are identical to Serial on their matching platform and Never on the respective other one.
Your type-checker/linter can pick up these constants and will infer only one if clause as reachable here, hence it will know exactly if Serial is the windows or linux (or another) variant on your current system or if you change the constant for the linter.
import os
import serial
if os.name == "nt":
    from serial.serialwin32 import Serial  # only reachable on Windows
    Win32Serial: TypeAlias = Serial
    PosixSerial = Never
    serial_port: Win32Serial = serial.Serial('COM1')
elif os.name == "posix":
    from serial.serialposix import Serial  # only reachable on Linux
    PosixSerial: TypeAlias = Serial
    Win32Serial = Never
    serial_port: PosixSerial = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
else:
   ...  # maybe lint as SerialBase

# Serial is platform-aware, however statically only one covered at the same time
another_port: Serial = serial.Serial(f"{name}")


The use of Never is optional, using it allows you to check to never reach linux code on windows (an alternative is also to use typing.assert_never). For example:
def windows_only(a: Win32Serial):
   ...

# Windows OK
# Posix: error: Type "Serial" is not assignable to type "Win32Serial" (reportArgumentType)
windows_only(serial_port)


Thanks for the suggestion. My question is not really about what version of Serial to import. That's handled by the pyserial package (import serial; s=serial.Serial(port_name)). My question was about how to conditionally annotate an instance of Serial based on the OS. I noticed later that the pyserial package is not annotated, so annotating the instance of Serial does not bring much, but I was wondering if there is a generic way to conditionally annotate variables, that is, as long as the condition is static and known to a linter.

Sorry that my answer went into another direction. The Serial variable (from the two platform submodules) would be a platform-aware variable that you can use anytime, it is statically one or the other as it is statically known to the linter because of the os.name guard (or rather constant literal). I've edited my answer to emphasize different ways to annotate it. Either via a constant platform-aware, however therefore ambiguous, variable Signal or via one of two TypeAliases that are identical to Signal or Unbound/Never. Depending on your preferences you can choose how to annotate.

It is the conditional import what solves the generic problem! Thanks for the idea and for the extra suggestions!

You can use the base class serial.serialutil.SerialBase.  Most of the methods are inheritied from that class.
from serial import SerialBase
serial_port: SerialBase = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')
serial_port: SerialBase = serial.Serial('COM1') 


I guess I could do this for the particular case of pyserial, though pyserial itself does not seem to be annotated so it is probably not worth the trouble, but I was wondering if there is generic approach to handle this type of situation.

Generally, this is the generic approach.  You reference the mutually inherited class
